# Numpy outer equality comparison with more than one element

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have two numpy arrays with which I'm doing an outer equality comparison

```
m = np.random.randint(4,size=(4,4,4))
ar = np.array([1,2,3])
x = np.equal.outer(ar,m)
```

This works well if I'm interested in testing every single element of `ar` in `m`. But what if I'd like to do more than one comparison in one go, say for example for elements `1 or 2`? One solution might be

```
x = np.equal.outer(1,m)|np.equal.outer(2,m)
```

which is fine for my example, but for my real data I need dozens of equality comparisons which also depend on user input, so I was looking for a better way to do this.

Comment: Use `np.isin` : `np.isin(x,[1,2])`.

Comment: Thanks Divakar. I suppose you meant `np.isin(m,[1,2])`, not `np.isin(x,[1,2])` right? The problem is I have other element groups I would like to compare. For example, how would you deal with having to do this over a series of lists/np.arrays (eg `l = [[1,2],[3,4,5],[6]]`)? Would you loop over the lists with a list comprehension `[np.isin(x,ll) ll in l]`?

Comment: Yes, should be `np.isin(m,[1,2])`. And yes looping would make most sense given the jagged structure. If you are looking for matches across all inner elements, use - `np.isin(m,np.concatenate(l))`. If not, `[np.isin(x,ll) ll in l]` makes sense.